Why is MIME type of uploaded rar files application/octet-stream and how to change it to application/rar?
I am using Vaadin 24 with Spring Boot 3.x and Tomcat as servlet container. When I try to upload file with Vaadin component, Upload, MIME type of uploaded file is application/octet-stream when I expect application/rar with rar files (or any other equivalent like application/vnd.rar or application/x-rar-compressed). It might be also worth noting that I am using Firefox web browser on Windows OS.
I set up success listener to Upload component like this
    addSucceededListener(success -> {
                val receiver = (MemoryBuffer) this.getReceiver();
                val length = success.getContentLength();
                val fileName = success.getFileName();
                val mime = success.getMIMEType(); // mime type is application/octet-stream
                ...
            });

Why it is application/octet-stream and what can I change, so the MIME type is application/rar or any other equivalent, so I can better handle the file?

So what does Fx send?

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; with any file (rar or jpeg...) so I guess the mime type decision happens somewhere in Vaadin/Spring.

And what is the Content/Mime-Type for your file sent inside this multipart POST?

Whatever you see on the server side, is what your browser sends you.
If you check the network-tab in your browser dev-tools, you will see
a request for the upload of the file (basically
http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/dynamic/resource/.../upload).
If you inspect the payload, you will see, that this is multipart
form-data and the part for the uploaded file contains a Content-Type
and this is what Vaadin gives you for getMIMEType().
Neither Spring nor Vaadin changes the value.  And you are well advised
to not trust whatever the client is sending here.


Why it is application/octet-stream?

Because Vaadin has a MIME mapping for many well known file extensions but apparently not for RAR. octet-stream is the most general MIME type which let you get the downloaded file as a binary stream. It's up to you how you treat the file on the server.

What can I change, so the MIME type is application/rar or any other equivalent, so I can better handle the file?

Why changing it? You can just read the file as a binary stream, write it into a directory of your choice. If you preserve the file extension (*.rar) it will be opened with the assigned application.

Yes, application/octet-stream is most general MIME type, which does not explain or add anything as answer to my question, except indication, that there is some handling in Spring or Vaadin that marks the file mime type to generic for some reason. I do not need to open it by some assigned application by file extension. My question was why this particular file type (rar) is being assigned application/octet-stream mime type in Vaadin/Spring when I upload the file. Other file types do not have generic mime. Surely, I can do whatever with the file or decide some logic by file extension...

Check my updated answer. It is maybe not exactly what you expected but it is not wrong - so no need to down-vote it. IMHO.
